# How to automate positioning of inner labels within a stacked barplot?

Tags: r, bar-chart

I frequently have to produce stacked bar plots with labels. The way I've been coding the labels is very time intensive and I wondered if there was a way to code things more efficiently. I would like the labels to be centered on each section of the bars. I'd prefer base R solutions.

```
stemdata <- structure(list( #had to round some nums below for 100% bar

A = c(7, 17, 76), 
B = c(14, 10, 76),
C = c( 14, 17, 69),
D = c( 4, 10, 86), 
E = c( 7, 17, 76),
F = c(4, 10, 86)), 

.Names = c("Food, travel, accommodations, and procedures",
         "Travel itinerary and dates",
        "Location of the STEM Tour stops",
         "Interactions with presenters/guides",
         "Duration of each STEM Tour stop",
        "Overall quality of the STEM Tour"
         ), 
class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -3L)) #4L=number of numbers in each letter vector#

# attach(stemdata)
print(stemdata)
par(mar=c(0, 19, 1, 2.1)) # this sets margins to allow long labels
barplot(as.matrix(stemdata), 

    beside = F, ylim = range(0, 10), xlim = range(0, 100),
    horiz = T, col=colors,  main="N=29", 
    border=F, las=1, xaxt='n', width = 1.03)

text(7, 2, "14%")
text(19, 2, "10%")
text(62, 2, "76%")

text(7, 3.2, "14%")
text(22.5, 3.2, "17%")
text(65.5, 3.2, "69%")

text(8, 4.4, "10%")
text(55, 4.4, "86%")

text(3.5, 5.6, "7%")
text(15, 5.6, "17%")
text(62, 5.6, "76%")

text(9, 6.9, "10%")
text(55, 6.9, "86%")
```

Comment: I'm getting an error when trying to run your plot. Can you double check it, and also provide an expected output of what your plot is supposed to look like?

Comment: I updated the code and a description of expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Staying base R as OP requested, we can easily automate the inner label positioning (i.e. `x` coordinates) within a small function.

```
xFun <- function(x) x/2 + c(0, cumsum(x)[-length(x)])
```

Now, it's good to know that `barplot` invisibly trows the `y` coordinates, we can catch them by assignment (here `byc <- barplot(.)`).

Eventually, just assemble coordinates and labels in data frame `labs` and "loop" through the `text` calls in a `sapply`. (Use `col="white"` or `col=0` for white labels as wished in the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56660496/6574038).)

```
# barplot
colors <- c("gold", "orange", "red")
par(mar=c(2, 19, 4, 2) + 0.1)  # expand margins

byc <- barplot(as.matrix(stemdata), horiz=TRUE, col=colors, main="N=29",  # assign `byc`
               border=FALSE, las=1, xaxt='n')

# labels
labs <- data.frame(x=as.vector(sapply(stemdata, xFun)),  # apply `xFun` here 
                   y=rep(byc, each=nrow(stemdata)),  # use `byc` here
                   labels=as.vector(apply(stemdata, 1:2, paste0, "%")), 
                   stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

invisible(sapply(seq(nrow(labs)), function(x)  # `invisible` prevents unneeded console output
  text(x=labs[x, 1:2], labels=labs[x, 3], cex=.9, font=2, col=0)))

# legend  (set `xpd=TRUE` to plot beyond margins!)
legend(-55, 8.5, legend=c("Medium","High", "Very High"), col=colors, pch=15, xpd=TRUE)

par(mar=c(5, 4, 4, 2) + 0.1)  # finally better reset par to default
```

***Result***

[image]

***Data***

```
stemdata <- structure(list(`Food, travel, accommodations, and procedures` = c(7, 
17, 76), `Travel itinerary and dates` = c(14, 10, 76), `Location of the STEM Tour stops` = c(14, 
17, 69), `Interactions with presenters/guides` = c(4, 10, 86), 
    `Duration of each STEM Tour stop` = c(7, 17, 76), `Overall quality of the STEM Tour` = c(4, 
    10, 86)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: I note the preference for base R was added in a later edit :) This is very good.

Comment: Thanks so much, this is very helpful! Is there a way for me to modify the code so that labels are NOT produced for sections of the graph less than 6%

Comment: @freeazabird Yeah, just run `labs$labels[labs$labels %in% paste0(0:(6*100)/100, "%")] <- ""` right after you've created `labs` (note that I' ve added `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` there). This even works up to two decimal places, just in case.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks, I'm at home doing my happy dance :-)

Comment: @freeazabird Nice picture of someone dancing because of my answer! BTW, would you mind always [**marking an answer as accepted**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/371738) when you ask a question to inform others that your problem has been solved?

Comment: Sure. So, I have one more question related to this. I have to create graphs like this frequently. What parts of the code do I need to modify when the dimensions of the dataset change? I tried replicating this with a different dataset and got errors.

Comment: @freeazabird Ahh thx, I think it's the `y` coord. part, see update in `labs <- data.frame(.)`, replaced with `nrow` to generalize .

Answer (score 1):

Would you consider a `tidyverse` solution?

```
library(tidyverse) # for dplyr, tidyr, tibble & ggplot2

stemdata %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = "id") %>% 
  gather(Var, Val, -id) %>% 
  group_by(Var) %>% 
  mutate(id = factor(id, levels = 3:1)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Var, Val)) + 
  geom_col(aes(fill = id)) + 
  coord_flip() + 
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(Val, "%")), 
            position = position_stack(0.5))
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting the error: Error in gather(., Var, Val, -id) : could not find function "gather" Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: `gather` is a function in the `tidyr` package. `library(tidyverse)` should load `tidyr` if you have done `install.packages("tidyverse")`. You can load the 4 packages separately (see comment in code), but why type more than needed :)