# How to automate data labels on descending bars?

Tags: r, plot

I want to automate data labels on a descending bar graph. I know how to automate the data labels, when the bars are not descending, which was answered in a previous question. I would like the solution to be in base R only.

I've tried adding this code, to the code below to automate the labels, but it doesn't work.

```
 # labels #HERE THE LABEL CODE DOESNT WORK AFTER DESCENDING
 xFun <- function(x) x/2 + c(0, cumsum(x)[-length(x)])
 labs <- data.frame(x=as.vector(sapply(byb, xFun)),  # apply `xFun` here 
               y=rep(byb, each=nrow(byb)),  # use `byc` here
               labels=as.vector(apply(byb, 1:2, paste0, "%")), 
               stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
 labs$labels[labs$labels %in% paste0(0:(8*100)/100, "%")] <- "" #masks 
 labels <8

 invisible(sapply(seq(nrow(labs)), function(x)  # `invisible` prevents 
 unneeded console output
 text(x=labs[x, 1:2], labels=labs[x, 3], cex=.9, font=2, col=0)))


  initialmth <- structure(list( 
  A = c( 10, 4),
  B = c(28, 18),
  C = c(9, 1), 
  D = c(39, 33),
  E = c(13, 8),
  F = c(37, 27), 
  G = c(30, 51), 
  H = c(31, 41)),  


  .Names = c("Math has been my worst subject ",
         "I would consider a career that uses math ",
         "Math is hard for me",
         "I am the type of student to do well in math",
         "I cannot do a good job with math",
         "I could do advanced work in math",
         "I can get good grades in math",
         "I am good at math"
    ), 
   class = "data.frame", 
   row.names = c(NA, -2L)) #4L=number of numbers in each letter vector#

   attach(initialmth)
   print(initialmth)
   par(mar=c(0, 17, 1, 2.1))
   colors <- c("slategray3", "dodgerblue4")


   par(mar=c(0, 17, 1, 2.1))
   initialmth <- initialmth[, order(colSums(initialmth))]
   colors <- c("slategray3", "dodgerblue4")
   byb <- barplot(as.matrix(initialmth), 
           beside = F, 
           horiz = T, col=colors,  main="N=96", xaxt="n", border=F, las=1)
```

Comment: The y axis bar labels are already rearranged. Did you mean something else?

Comment: Yes, I meant data labels, not bar labels. I will edit my question to reflect this.

Comment: Didn't I answer that already in the [comment to the answer of your quite similar question today](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56909848/6574038)?

Comment: Probably it's related to `attach`, I didn't use it and got what you want. I recommend to **never ever** use `attach` it's very bad and it'll get you into hell's kitchen.

Comment: Please screenshot current graph and then desired graph (i.e., better to show than tell) where latter may require image software since you cannot produce it in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For explanations please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56660978/6574038) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56909848/6574038) preceding answers.

```
initialmth <- initialmth[, order(colSums(initialmth))]

xFun <- function(x) x/2 + c(0, cumsum(x)[-length(x)])

par(mar=c(0, 17, 1, 2.1))
colors <- c("slategray3", "dodgerblue4")
byc <- barplot(as.matrix(initialmth), 
               beside = F, ylim = range(0, 15), xlim = range(0, 100),
               horiz = T, col=colors,  main="N=96", xaxt="n", border=F, las=1, width 
               = 1.45)
# labels
labs <- data.frame(x=as.vector(sapply(initialmth, xFun)),  # apply `xFun` here 
                   y=rep(byc, each=nrow(initialmth)),  # use `byc` here
                   labels=as.vector(apply(initialmth, 1:2, paste0, "%")), 
                   stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
labs$labels[labs$labels %in% paste0(0:(8*100)/100, "%")] <- "" #masks labels <8

invisible(sapply(seq(nrow(labs)), function(x)  # `invisible` prevents unneeded console output
  text(x=labs[x, 1:2], labels=labs[x, 3], cex=.9, font=2, col=0)))
```

[image]

#### Data

```
initialmth <- structure(list(`Math has been my worst subject ` = c(10, 4), 
    `I would consider a career that uses math ` = c(28, 18), 
    `Math is hard for me` = c(9, 1), `I am the type of student to do well in math` = c(39, 
    33), `I cannot do a good job with math` = c(13, 8), `I could do advanced work in math` = c(37, 
    27), `I can get good grades in math` = c(30, 51), `I am good at math` = c(31, 
    41)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: Thanks. I have one more question related to this code. I added gridlines by adding the following code:                                                                                                                              
     
       grid(nx = NULL, ny = nx, col = "lightgray", lty = "dotted",
       lwd = par("lwd"), equilogs = TRUE)                                                                                       The  gridlines show up on top of the graph bars. Is there a way to place them behind the bars?